# Keep only "naked" text in a tag

Tags: jquery

I have this basic HTML:

```
<h2>Edit <small>additional text</small></h2>
<div id="result"></div>
```

I can easily get the "Edit" ('naked') text, removing the "small" tag:

```
var onlytext = $( "h2" ).prop( "firstChild" ).nodeValue;
$( "#result" ).append(onlytext);
```

Here is the fiddle, and so far so good: http://jsfiddle.net/822dm/

Now I'd like to add an icon before the text, getting this:

```
<h2><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit <small>additional text</small></h2>
<div id="result"></div>
```

But, in this case, the javascript stops working: http://jsfiddle.net/822dm/1/

I tried `var onlytext = $( "h2" ).prop( "firstChild" ).text();`: this removes the icon but keeps the "small" tag text

Please any help? Consider that "i" and "small" tags can be optional
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's because `firstChild` is no longer the word `Edit`, but it's now `fa fa-edit` class.

Comment: That's right, Alex, but how do I tell "keep only text that is not inside a tag - aka naked text"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you've to do is to remove the child elements of the `<h2>` tag. So that you'll only get the `Edit` as text.

Check out this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/822dm/5/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Similar to what I've put. Don't know whether it's better to do 5 JQuery functions or a Regex Replace, or if it even matters :)

Comment: @JamieBarker I agree with you jamie. A simple regex solution you've posted is better. But the OP is more specific to jQuery solutions i guess

Answer (score 3):

One possible approach:

```
var onlytext = $('h2').contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType===3});
$('#result').append(onlytext.clone());
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4yA7D/). It's simple, really: with [**.contents()**](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) only the *immediate* children of the selected element are collected, then the result is filtered so only text nodes are left. Actually, this line...

```
.contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType===3});
```

... is a very common idiom when you deal with text in jQuery.

Comment: This seems nice, but "Edit" text disappeared from the <h2> in the fiddle!

Answer (score 2):

You could use Regex to remove all html tags:

http://jsfiddle.net/jabark/822dm/6/

```
var onlytext = $('h2').html();
onlytext = onlytext.replace(/\<.*?\>[^\<]*?\<\/.*?\>/g, '');
$( "#result" ).append(onlytext);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to add a hack for that?

Change your HTML a bit and warp your text in `span` tag

```
<h2><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <span>Edit</span> <small>additional text</small></h2>
```

and then you can do something like `$("h2 span").text()`.

Comment: if you will avoid extra markup then you need to add extra logical code in JS, which is not good.